# Installing VSTO 4.0 Causes VSTO 3.0 Addin to quit working

Tags: ms-office, vsto, office-interop

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 yesterday.  As part of that I installed VSTO 4.0.  Now when I run any Office application, my VSTO 3.0 addins fail to load.  The error in the event log is

Customization URI: file:///H:/PathToMyAddin/MyAddin.vsto
Exception: Customization does not have the permissions required to create an application domain.

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException:
>   Customization does not have the
>   permissions required to create an
>   application domain. --->
>   System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Customized functionality in this
>   application will not work because the
>   administrator has listed
>   file:///H:/PathToMyAddin/MyAddin.vsto
>   as untrusted. Contact your
>   administrator for further assistance. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.RuntimeUtilities.VerifySolutionUri(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String
>   solutionLocation, String manifestName,
>   String documentName, Boolean
>   showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr
>   hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed
>   was: MyComputer

It seems like like maybe this is due to it trying to load different version of .NET is the same process/AppDomain.  However the error would indicate it's some sort of permissions issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that VSTO 4 doesn't trust add-ins on network locations by default.  However, by adding the following registry key

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\vsto runtime Setup\v4]
"EnableVSTOLocalUNC"=dword:00000001
```

and re-enabling my add-in, it appeared to work as expected again.

Another option for some is just to install the add-in on the user's local machine instead of on a network location

Comment: what about trusting that location in Excel trusted locations (excel options)?

Comment: Not sure about Excel, but adding the location as a Word trusted location didn't help me.

Comment: I have placed the SETUP.EXE and the project.MSI outputs from my Setup Project on a Network Drive (mapped from both my dev PC and my target PC). When I run SETUP on the target PC, it seems to install without complaint but it won't respect the LoadBehavior setting (to load the addin at the startup of Outlook). I think I should try your registry fix but if that works on 1 test PC can you think of a way to avoid such a manual fix for all PCs to be deployed with my Outlook add-in? (Will report back soon on this approach).

Comment: Also, if you are on a 64-bit OS, the key will be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4